# How do i calculate if with multiple criteria and for easy can be done in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, ifs

I want to drive an if formula for the following criteria, but the formula is becoming too long. can it be done through VBA. i have 31 columns based on the number of days on a month.

1st Criteria
Designations:

- Manager - Man
- Asst Manager - AsstMan
- Executive - Exe
- Supervisor - Sup
- Officer - Off
- Front line Officer - Flo
- Driver - dvr
- Female Staff - FS

2nd Criteria
Attendance

- P = Present
- A = Absent
- W = Weekly off
- V = Vacation
- L = Leave without pay
- D = Left the Job

I have derived a sheet which tells me on the basis of their ID number their attendance. 
 - Now i want to calculate their per day salary on the basis of their designation and attendance.
 - On the basis of their designation, attendance and where they are performing their job (kind of location allowance).

Following is the if formula i have derived:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("Man"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("P"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("AsstMan"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("P"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("Exe"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("P"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("FLO"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("P"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("FS"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("P"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("Man"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("A"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("Exe"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("A"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("FS"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("A"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("FLO"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("A"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("AsstMan"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("A"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("Man"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("W"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("AsstMan"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("W"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("FLO"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("W"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("Exe"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("W"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("FS"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("W"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("Man"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("V"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("AsstMAn"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("V"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("Exe"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("V"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("FLO"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("V"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("FS"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("V"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("Man"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("L"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("AssMAn"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("L"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("Exe"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("L"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("FLO"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("L"=Attendence!E4),0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($B4=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))*("FS"=INDIRECT("'"&E$3&"'!$G$4:$G$1000"))*("L"=Attendence!E4),0)),"",-(ABBR!$C$79/$E$1)),-(ABBR!$C$78/$E$1)),-(ABBR!$C$77/$E$1)),-(ABBR!$C$76/$E$1)),-(ABBR!$C$75/$E$1)),(ABBR!$C$79/$E$1)),(ABBR!$C$78/$E$1)),(ABBR!$C$77/$E$1)),(ABBR!$C$76/$E$1)),(ABBR!$C$75/$E$1)),(ABBR!$C$79/$E$1)),(ABBR!$C$78/$E$1)),(ABBR!$C$77/$E$1)),(ABBR!$C$76/$E$1)),(ABBR!$C$75/$E$1)),("0")),("0")),("0")),("0")),("0")),(ABBR!$C$79/$E$1)),(ABBR!$C$78/$E$1)),(ABBR!$C$77/$E$1)),(ABBR!$C$76/$E$1)),(ABBR!$C$75/$E$1))
```

Ask if i have missed anything. Need Help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sample data, how this is laid out etc are all important bits of information for knowing how to address this.

Comment: The large formula could be broken down into smaller formulas, where each smaller formula is in a separate column.  For example, each `IF` statement could be its own column.  Then a final column which uses the results of the other columns.  The columns which represent the intermediate results could also be hidden.

Comment: Following is the link for the Sample Data

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CVZt2f7SJFbNPoIKZyTi2dJR7xI5Padp

Comment: Formula is too long and can not be used in the formula bar as it exceeds the total number of characters. kindly help develop a VBA code for it

Answer (score 0):

Use a select...case... statement (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement)

it'll be easier to understand and easier to code